# How to stop a threading variable in python

Tags: python

As the title says I am programming a task at my school, and I have a variable to check the wounds a player has suffered, but the wounds equal the death amount it doesn't stop the game like planned and continuously prints the 'You Died' instead of just the once. Any tips would be very helpful

```
import sys
import threading
import multiprocessing

wounds = 2

def die():
    print("You Died")
    sys.exit()
    return

def woundCount():
    global wounds
    if wounds >= 3:
        die()
        return

def checkdeath():
    threading.Timer(0.5, checkdeath).start()
    woundCount()
    return

####This should print the wounds and then kill your character.
print(wounds)
wounds = wounds + 1
print(wounds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so because the method `checkdeath()` does not check `wounds` (or if you are already dead) before firing another `checkdeath()`. You can fix it by this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import threading
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> wounds = 2
>>> is_dead = False
>>> def die():
        global is_dead
        is_dead = True
        print("You Died")
        sys.exit()
        return

>>> def woundCount():
        global wounds
        if wounds >= 3:
            die()


>>> def checkdeath():
        if is_dead:
            return
        threading.Timer(0.5, checkdeath).start()
        woundCount()
        return

>>> checkdeath()
>>> wounds += 1
>>> You Died
```

So, whenever you are dead, `is_dead` becomes `True`. And as you are checking if you are already dead before starting another thread, the death notice is printed only once.